# Parsing into array in swift 3

Tags: json, swift

```
class DataService {

    var itemArray : [Item] = []

    func getJSON() {
        Alamofire.request(API_URL, method: .get).response {
            response in
            if response.error == nil {
                self.parseJSON(json: JSON(response.data!))
            }
            else {
                print("Connection Unavailable")
            }
        }
    }

    func parseJSON(json: JSON) {
        for item in json["item_info"] {
            let temp = Item(title: String(describing:(item.1["title"])),
                                        desc: String(describing:(item.1["description"])),
                                        itemURL: String(describing:(item.1["url"]))
            PutItem(item: temp)
        }
    }

    func PutItem(item: Item) {
        itemArray.append(item)
    } 

}
```

Here is the class `Item`

```
class Item {

    let title: String
    let desc: String
    let itemURL: String

    init(title: String, desc: String, itemURL: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.desc = desc
        self.itemURL = itemURL
    }
}
```

Json response is like this:

```
"item_info": [{
    "title": "title1",
    "description": "desc1",
    "url": "url1"
}, {
    "title": "title2",
    "description": "desc2",
    "url": "url2",
}
]
```

I am trying to fetch and parse a Json such that I store information for all the items in that Json into an array `itemArray`, but the problem is that the `itemArray` always appears to be empty, even after `parseJSON()` populates it correctly and is available to use inside the `PutItem()` method. Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: can you please post the json?

Comment: @PranavKasetti posted in the description, have a look

Comment: If you print your json right before trying to access it, what do you get ?

Comment: @Alex If i print it from the PutItem() function, it prints fine as usual. But if I use the variable itemArray in another Swift file, it appears to be empty.

Comment: @iVvaibhav what you are describing is a classic issue of not understanding asynchronous programming. You are retrieving values from a network request, which is an asynchronous process, so most probably you are trying to access the values before they would actually be set up. Study asynchronous programming in detail, it is a crucial topic if you plan to use network APIs.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, you could try changing your parse method to this:

```
   func parseJSON(json: JSON) {

         for item in json["item_info"] {

                 if let title = item["name"] as? String, let description = item["description"] as? String, let url = item["url"] as? String {

                       let yourItem = Item(title: title, desc: description, itemURL: url) 

                      // Here you can do whatever you want using your Item.
                 }
            }
      }
```

And it would work just fine. :)

*Note that you could use Guard statements as well.*

Note: While it's not directly related to your question, I would also suggest you not to use a capital letter for the first letter of your function name, as it may be confusing for other people reading your code. You should write your method putItem() to respect the naming convention.

Comment: Could you post that again. Nothing appears in here.

Comment: Sorry I had a problem with formatting on my phone, I will update my answer from my computer.

Comment: I updated my answer, please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Note here that you re calling `parseJSON(json: JSON)` method only after you have got the response from API request.That is the reason why you got the value correctly when you try to print value from same file/class.

What happens when you try to access this variable from another class?. At that time, you don't know whether the value of `itemArray` has been set or not while you try to access from another class since API requests are asynchronous.  So the value can be empty at the time of accessing variable.

Solution:

```
class DataService {

 static let sharedInstance = DataService()

 func getJSON() -> [Item] {
      var itemArray : [Item] = []

      Alamofire.request(API_URL, method: .get).response {
           response in
           if response.error == nil {

                let json = JSON(response.data!)
                for item in json["item_info"] {
                     let temp = Item(title: item["title"] as? String ?? ""),
                                     desc: item["description" as? String ?? ""),
                                     itemURL: item["url"] as? String ?? "")
                     itemArray.append(item)
                }
                return itemArray
           }
           else {
                print("Connection Unavailable")
           }
      }
 }
```

you can call `DataService.sharedInstance.getJSON()` to get `itemArray`

Comment: This is helpful. I understand where I went wrong. Can you explain how can it be corrected?

Comment: How you are accessing the variable? Can you post the code?

Comment: I am just creating an instance of DataService class and using it to access variables to other classes. Not sure if this is the right way.

Comment: So when is this `getJSON()` method called?

Comment: From viewDidLoad of project initial view controller

Comment: Cannot return from the Alamofire closure. Had to place the return statement on the bottom just before the method ends but it still has the same effect